# Why the word “a” can be used here?

Tags: indefinite-article, plural-forms

> Fairtrade coffee sales ranged from 0.8-3 million euros over a 6-year period in these five countries, whereas banana sales also mostly clustered between 0.6 and 2 million euros, with Switzerland the outlier *at **a** huge 15 million euros*.

I don’t get why it can say “at a huge 15 million euros”? Isn’t “euros” a plural word?

Comment: I feel like there have been a lot of questions here about the use of articles with things that don't normally take articles, like "a smiling Joe Biden" or whatever.  I'll see if I can find some.

Comment: You have overlooked the inversion in the question title.  It should be _Why can the word "a" be used here?_

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, the object of the preposition *at* is a number, a value, or a figure.  The person was thinking of Switzerland's banana sales as a singular entry on a ledger.  It's effectively short for *with Switzerland the outlier at a huge value of 15 million euros.*

A similar example might be *the runner finished the race in a blazing (time of) three minutes.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "euros" is plural here, because of the number "15 million". But "a" does not modify "euros". We can demonstrate this by replacing "a" with a plural equivalent:

> **...with Switzerland the outlier at **several** huge 15 million euros.*

Another clue is "huge". It doesn't modify "euros" because "*15 million **huge** euros*" is nonsense. "Huge" refers to the total amount of 15 million euros, and therefore so does "a".

So, the overall meaning is that 15 million euros is a huge amount.

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to the total value of sales, which is a singular quantity, rather than the individual euros that make up those sales.

Comment: Yes. 15 million euros/pounds/dollars (etc) **is** a lot of money.